# setTimeout Não Espera O Tempo

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho Este Código:

```
<html>
    <form method="POST">
        <textarea name="txt" value="" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea>
        <br></br>
        <input type="button" name="" value="Message" onClick="btfunc()" style="width:100; height:100" wrap="soft">
    </form>
    <script charset="utf-8">
        var strs = ["C++", "Python"];
        var i = 0;
        var strpos = 0;

        function btfunc()
        {
            while (i < strs[strpos].length)
            {

                if (strpos > strs.length - 1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i == strs[strpos].length - 1)
                    {
                        document.forms[0].elements[0].value += strs[strpos].charAt(i);
                        i = -1;
                        strpos++;
                        document.forms[0].elements[0].value += "\n";
                        i++;
                        setTimeout(btfunc, 2000);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.forms[0].elements[0].value += strs[strpos].charAt(i);
                        i++;
                        setTimeout(btfunc, 100);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    </script>

</html>
```

Quando Clico No Botão Ele Insere Todo O Texto Sem Ir Pausando Nos setTimeouts, Pq Isso Acontece ?

Comment: Esse código está meio confuso. Pode explicar o que quer fazer? (para além do problema com os timeouts...)

Comment: Ele vai escrevendo o que estiver na **array** e de um elemento para o outro ele pula uma linha na **textarea**, só que com um efeito de (Digitando) exemplo:C (0.1Sec Depois) + (0.1Sec Depois) + Entendeu ?

Comment: Depois de acabar um elemento ele pula uma linha espera dois segundos e começa a escrever o outro elemento da **array**, o código funciona do jeito que quero o problema é que ele não pausa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema principal é estar a chamar `setTimeout(func, 100)`. Ou seja, o ciclo `while` corre e cria uma "lista de espera" com esses `setTimeout`. Uma vez que o código acaba a execução  ainda antes de o primeiro `setTimeout` ser corrido na prática todos os `setTimeout` apontam para o mesmo momento e são escritos ao mesmo tempo. A solução é conseguir atrasar a execução através da criação  de valores crescentes para cada `setTimeout`.

Tentando misturar a sua ideia com a minha lógica sugiro isto:

```js
var strs = ["C++", "Python"];
var i = 0;

function maquinaEscrever(str) {
    var campo = document.forms[0].elements[0];
    var pedacos = str.split('');

    pedacos.forEach(function (letra, index) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            campo.value += letra;
            if (index + 1 == pedacos.length){
                setTimeout(btfunc, 2000);
                campo.value += '\n';
                i++;
            }
        }, index * 100);
    });
}

function btfunc() {
    if (strs[i]) maquinaEscrever(strs[i]);
    else i = 0;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
    <textarea name="txt" value="" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea>
    <br></br>
    <input type="button" name="" value="Message" onClick="btfunc()" style="width:100; height:100" wrap="soft" />
</form>
```

Assim divide o código em partes. Criei uma `callback` que é o que chama a função `btfunc` de novo depoid da primeira *string* ter sido escrita.

Criei uma "máquina de escrever" que no fundo parte uma *stirng* em letras e escreve uma  uma seperadas por `100` milisegundos. Usei o index/posição da letra na string para fazer essa diferença de milisegundos visto esse `forEach` correr imediatamente.

Não percebo porque usa um textarea, podia usar uma div, mas não mexi nessa parte pois o problema não estava aí.

Comment: Estou analisando seu código aqui, mas você sabe pq os setTimeout não estavam funcionando ?

Comment: @axell13 sim, porque todos eram corridos ao mesmo tempo. Os `100ms` que está a colocar vão ser todos corridos ao mesmo tempo porque o loop não pára para esperar o `setTimeout`. Daí eu ter usado `i * 100`. Que na prática é `100`, `200`, `300`, etc.

Comment: @axell13 tenho de ir, eu tinha uma resposta sobre esse problema algures aqui no SOpt (bem explicada). Se não compreender ainda o problema vou colocar aqui amanhã. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Me ajudou sim, obrigado, o importante aqui foi que `setTimeout` dentro de loop não da certo.

Comment: A parte que gostaria de intender direito é a de multiplicar o index por 100, o que tem no setTimeout que tem q faze isto ? A propósito quando eu tento colocar @Sergio no inicio do comentário ele não sai.

Comment: @axell13 Todas as "passadas" do seu `while` ocorrem muito perto umas das outras. Como disse o Sergio, os timeouts expiram todos juntos. Multiplicar o index por 100 é uma maneira de "afastar" os timers uns dos outros.

Comment: @bfavaretto Entendo mas tudo deveria acontecer normalmente, pra min isso parece mais um **bug** da linguagem do que falta de conhecimento do programador. Em outras linguagens por exemplo não tem problema nenhum botar um sleep dentro de um loop.

Comment: @axell13 `setTimeout` funciona diferente de um sleep, o callback dele é assíncrono. Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950/como-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-funciona-em-javascript/16960#16960

Comment: Sim, eu sabia que era diferente, só acho sacanagem não poder parar a execução mesmo, mas obrigado.

Comment: @axell13 parar a execução em JavaScript é considerado um erro de programação, mesmo que seja prático. Ás vezes dá vontade de fazer um pedido ajax syncrono mas as razões para não fazer são maiores. Dá para fazer por exemplo com setInterval criar um loop mas neste caso acho que seria melhor como eu sugeri.

Comment: @Sergio Sim, Só Uma Pergunta Não Sei Se Pode Responder, Quando Você Coloca `split('')` Ok Normal Mas Quando Você Coloca `split("")` Ele Converte Essa Constante Pra `''` ?

Comment: @axell13 o que quer dizer com "Ele Converte Essa Constante"? que constante? usar aspas duplas ou simples é igual no caso de não ter nada dentro das aspas.

Comment: @Sergio Esquece Essa Parte, Só Pra Saber Mesmo Quando Eu Coloco `""` Ele Perde Tempo Transformando Isso Em `''` ? Ou Tanto Faz Vai Ter O Mesmo Desempenho ? Mesmo Que Mude Muito Pouco Mesmo E Seja Imperceptível Ele Perde Tempo Transformando ?

Comment: @axell13 não há diferenca entre aspas simples e duplas. Por norma usa-se `'` em JavaScript pois no HTML usa-se `"` por norma, dessa maneira chocam menos.

Comment: @Sergio É Porque Por Exemplo No Python Se Você Colocar "Hello" No Console Ele Vai Retornar 'Hello' Era Essa Minha Dúvida.

Comment: @Sergio Por Isso Que Eu Achava Que Ele Tinha Que Transformar

Comment: @axell13, eu falei em JavaScript. Noutras linguagens é/pode ser diferente. Dê uma olhada aqui por exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4652/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-aspas-simples-e-duplas-em-php

Comment: @Sergio Link Interessante, Agora Sei Quando É Melhor Usar Cada Uma, Obrigado.