# Função como parâmetro em funções em jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções, parâmetros

Sempre usei algumas funções sem entender de fato o que estava acontecendo e de onde vinham tais parâmetros. Eu falo do seguinte:

Exemplo 1:

```
$("#link").on("click", function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Exemplo 2:

```
$.getJSON("http://minhaurl", {id: 20}, function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        console.log(value.property)
    })
});
```

No primeiro exemplo, de onde vem esse `event`? O que me deixa em dúvida é que não importa o nome desse parâmetro, sempre vai dar certo. E eu não declarei ele em lugar algum!

No segundo, da mesma forma. De onde vem o `data`, que pode ser mudado para qualquer outro nome assim como no primeiro exemplo?

Simplesmente uso seguindo exemplos, mas preciso compreender o funcionamento.

Alguém pode me explicar?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sua atitude é louvável gostaria que mais programadores fossem assim.

Estas funções são chamadas de [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101). Elas são criadas justamente para responder com uma ação a algo que o ambiente onde sua aplicação está rodando exige. Normalmente são passados dados para funções. Esta é uma forma de passar algoritmos para funções. Note que esta função que você está criando é por si só um parâmetro de uma função que você está chamando. É assim que o [*callback*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback) ([em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29)) funciona.

Neste caso você não vê as chamadas em lugar algum porque isso é feito dentro do navegador ou pelo menos dentro de alguma biblioteca que você está usando. Você não vê as chamadas porque elas não são responsabilidade da sua aplicação.

Note que nada impede de você mesmo criar um mecanismo assim dentro da sua aplicação. Existem algumas vantagens em fazer isto em alguma situações dando bastante flexibilidade e poder à aplicação. Claro que se criar todo o mecanismo na sua aplicação você terá que criar a chamada a estas funções em algum lugar.

Esta é uma excelente forma de comunicação de partes que não se conhecem, muito usado para tratar [eventos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evento_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) ([em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(computing))), assincronicidade como a usada em [AJAX](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) ([em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))) ou mesmo para completar com alguma ação que um módulo precisa mas deve ser fornecida pelo usuário daquele módulo. Muitas vezes esse módulo é uma [API](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_aplica%C3%A7%C3%B5es) ([em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)).

Então você tem que estudar a API que está usando. Tem que procurar pela documentação que explique o que aquilo faz, porque ela é importante e as diversas formas de usar. Sabendo de todas informações você poderá ser muito mais criativo. Isso é o que diferencia os verdadeiros desenvolvedores dos seguidores de receita de bolo.

Na documentação tem a assinatura da função. Ou seja, lá mostra como deve ser declarada a função que a API vai chamar. Mostra os parâmetros que ela deve receber e o que ela deve retornar. Normalmente descreve ela dá exemplos do mínimo que deve ser feito no corpo da função. Você pode fazer o que e do jeito que quiser internamente, só precisa respeitar os protocolos de entrada e saída e fazer algo minimamente útil que em alguns casos pode até mesmo ser nada.

Em alguns casos pode ser exagero usar algo assim. Nos exemplos usados eu não sei dizer se há alguma vantagem real em usar o `each()`. No fundo ele substitui o uso do [`for each`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in) para deixar o código menor, até onde eu sei nada mais que isto, pelo menos neste caso. Diminuir o código é bom mas [não é algo sem custo](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance--net-5551), isto não deveria ser o objetivo principal. Muitas vezes é melhor usar o [Vanilla JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/101) pelo menos porque ele é [muito mais rápido](https://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a) mas neste caso é menos flexível também e a legibilidade é questionável.

Mas este é um caso fácil de entender:

```
// args is for internal usage only
each: function( obj, callback, args ) { //note que args não faz parte da API pública
    var i = 0,
        length = obj.length,
        isArray = isArraylike( obj );

    if ( args ) { //aqui trata quando há algo interno acontecendo
        if ( isArray ) {
            for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
                if ( callback.apply( obj[ i ], args ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for ( i in obj ) {
                if ( callback.apply( obj[ i ], args ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    // A special, fast, case for the most common use of each
    } else { //tratamento do caso público que é que nos interessa
        if ( isArray ) { //tratamento especial se for um array
            for ( ; i < length; i++ ) { //varrrrá todo array passado
                if ( callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] ) === false ) {
                    break; //encerra quando a chama acima falhar
                }
            }
        } else { //outros objetos
            for ( i in obj ) { //vai analisar cada elemento do objeto passado
                if ( callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] ) === false ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return obj;
},
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/CallbackExamplejQuery.js).

[Fonte](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js).

Esse é o `each()` do jQuery que você não sabe de onde vem a chamada.

Note que quem faz a operação individual é a função `callback.call` que faz parte do JavaScript. É uma função que serve justamente para chamar outras funções que são passadas como argumento. Em última análise a função [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) será chamada. Ela tem a infra-estrutura necessária para realizar a efetiva execução da função desejada.

Isso não tem nada com meta-programação. Pelo menos não diretamente.

Documentação do [`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Documentação do [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Documentação do [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

Comment: Opa! Valeu! Bem completa a sua explicação. Vou ler na documentação também.

Answer (score 5):

A resposta do @Maniero foi na mosca, destaco este trecho:

> Normalmente são passados dados para funções. Esta é uma forma de passar algoritmos para funções. Note que esta função que você está criando é por si só um parâmetro de uma função que você está chamando. É assim que o *callback* funciona.
>
> Neste caso você não vê as chamadas em lugar algum porque isto é feito dentro do navegador ou pelo menos dentro de alguma biblioteca que você está usando. Você não vê as chamadas porque elas não são responsabilidade da sua aplicação.

### `.on("click", function(event) { })`

O seu primeiro exemplo atribui um *listener* para um evento de clique. Ali você define qual será o *callback* de uma operação assíncrona, uma operação que não vai ocorrer imediatamente (e sim quando o usuário interagir por meio de um clique).

Quando o clique ocorre, o browser cria um [objeto que representa o evento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) e passa isso para o listener correspondente. Esse objeto é o que você recebe se estiver escutando o evento com JavaScript puro:

```
elemento.addEventListener('click', function(evento) {
    // estou falando deste objeto aqui -------^
});
```

O jQuery vai embrulhar o objeto original em um objeto customizado, normalizado para maior compatibilidade entre browsers, e é isso que a função no seu código recebe.

#### "não importa o nome desse parâmetro, sempre vai dar certo"

É verdade. Pense bem, você está definindo uma função. Quem define a função é que nomeia os parâmetros. Na verdade você nem precisa criar parâmetros nomeados, se [os argumentos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32448/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-par%C3%A2metro-e-argumento) forem passados você ainda pode acessá-los pela ordem via `arguments[0]`, `arguments[1]` etc. Quem é responsável por chamar a função e passar os argumentos é primeiro o browser, e depois o jQuery que passa isso adiante para a sua função.

### `$.getJSON(url, {}, function(data){ })`

O funcionamento é bem parecido com o do *listener* de clique, com a diferença que o evento assíncrono não é originado por uma ação do usuário, e sim pela chegada da resposta solicitada ao servidor. Daí em diante é tudo igual: o browser chama uma função e fornece a resposta (porém neste caso ela não é passada para a função, [fica disponível como propriedade do objeto `XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)). O jQuery pega essa resposta, embrulha num [objeto cusomizado](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), e passa esse objeto para a sua função.

### Aprofundamento

Se quiser entender melhor como o browser trata as operações assíncronas do JavaScript , talvez esta pergunta e resposta ajudem: *[Como programação assíncrona funciona em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950/como-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-funciona-em-javascript)*.

Answer (score 3):

Para você entender os parâmetros recebidos pelas funções do jQuery, você precisa conferir na [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/).

Por exemplo, na função [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). A forma mais simples de utilizá-la é a seguinte:

```
.on( events, handler )
```

Como você já sabe, o parâmetro `events` recebe uma `string` com os eventos desejados e o `handler` recebe uma função para ser executada quando o evento for disparado.

Na documentação, o jQuery informa que o `handler` irá receber os seguintes parâmetros:

```
( Event eventObject [, Anything extraParameter ] [, ... ] )
```

O primeiro parâmetro será um objeto do tipo `Event`. Os outros são opcionais e não vem ao caso.

Resumindo, quando um dos parâmetros é uma função (callback), você deve olhar na documentação para verificar quais parâmetros a mesma irá receber.

---

Obs: outra forma de conferir quais parâmetros sua função está recebendo é conferindo todos os argumentos que a função recebeu.

```
console.log(arguments);
// a variável arguments é um array contendo
// todos os argumentos recebidos pela função
```