# Duvida requisição ajax com angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hoje ao realizar uma requisição ajax para uma url contendo um json para armazenar dentro de um vetor, o valor do vetor só esta preenchido dentro do método http, e fora ele da erro, eu fiz 2 `console.log` o primeiro funciona o seguindo volta um array vazio, segue o código.

```
myApp.controller('PrincipalController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.dadosEmail = [];

    $http.get('/dados-email.json').success(function(retorno) {
         $scope.dadosEmail = retorno; 
         console.log($scope.dadosEmail);
    }).error(function(msg) {
        alert('Erro');    
    });

    console.log($scope.dadosEmail);

    $scope.ordenaPorNome = function() {
        $scope.dadosEmail.sort(function(a, b) {

            //Resolve o problema de letras maisculas e minusculas.
            a = a.toLowerCase();
            b = b.toLowerCase();

            if (a.nome > b.nome) {
                return 1;    
            }
            if (b.nome > a.nome) {
                return -1;   
            } 

            return 0;
        });    
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa colocar todo o código que depende do resultado da requisição dentro do *callback* de sucesso. Na posição em que está, esse código executa antes de o resultado estar disponível, pois a requisição HTTP é feita de maneira assíncrona.

Seu código portanto deveria ficar assim:

```
myApp.controller('PrincipalController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.dadosEmail = [];

    $http.get('/dados-email.json').success(function(retorno) {
         $scope.dadosEmail = retorno; 

         $scope.ordenaPorNome = function() {
             $scope.dadosEmail.sort(function(a, b) {

                 //Resolve o problema de letras maisculas e minusculas.
                 a = a.toLowerCase();
                 b = b.toLowerCase();

                 if (a.nome > b.nome) {
                     return 1;    
                 }
                 if (b.nome > a.nome) {
                     return -1;   
                 } 

                 return 0;
             });    
         };
    }).error(function(msg) {
        alert('Erro');    
    });
});
```

Como a função `$scope.ordenaPorNome` só será definida depois da resposta da requisição chegar, você também precisa ter o cuidado de não chamá-la antes que ela exista.

Comment: Teria algum modo de evitar esse problema sem envolver minha função dentro da minha requisição AJAX?

Comment: O máximo que você pode fazer é chamar uma função no `success` e passar para ela o retorno. Dentro dessa outra função você definiria a `ordenaPorNome`. É a mesma coisa em termos de fluxo de execução, só muda a organização visual do código.

Comment: Achei que o código fica um pouco desorganizado, mas realmente você estava certo, muito obrigado :)

Comment: Pra falar a verdade eu também acho. Eu não colocaria tudo dentro do callback, criaria funções separadas e encadeadas, como expliquei no outro comentário. O código que postei foi mais para explicar o fluxo de execução assíncrono mesmo. Talvez isto aqui te ajude (apesar de um pouco teórico demais): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950/como-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-funciona-em-javascript