# Como executar "setInterval" sem delay inicial?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Neste código abaixo, ele atualiza uma div a cada 20 segundos. Só que ao entrar na página tenho que esperar 20 segundos para ele aparecer. Gostaria que ele já aparecesse de início, ao entrar na página.

```
<div id="latestData"><img src="img/loading3.gif" /></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       setInterval(function() {
          $.get("includes/principal/contador_mapa.php", function (result) {    
              //nome da pagina com o select mysql
              $('#latestData').html(result);  // nome da DIV
          });
       }, 20000); // segundos
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Não sei se é uma boa ideia usar `setInterval` nesse caso. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77764/por-que-dizem-que-recursividade-de-settimeout-%C3%A9-melhor-que-setinterval/77765#77765

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode criar uma função com o código dessa requisição e chamá-la antes de colocá-la no `setInterval`.

```
$(function () {
    function getContadorMapa() {
        $.get("includes/principal/contador_mapa.php", function (result) {
            $('#latestData').html(result);
        });
    }

    getContadorMapa(); // primeira chamada
    setInterval(getContadorMapa, 20000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer uma função à parte que se retorna a sí própria, e quando fôr executada a primeira vez deixa-se a sí prória como argumento no `setInterval`.

```
$(function () {
    var $latestData = $('#latestData'); // para ficar em cache e não precisar de fazer mais que 1 vez
    function contadorMapa() {
        $.get("includes/principal/contador_mapa.php", function (result) {
            $latestData.html(result);
        });
        return contadorMapa; // <-- assim quando fôr executada a primeira vez deixa no seu lugar a função
    }
    setInterval(getContadorMapa(), 20000);
});
```