# Como resolver o problema do setinterval que so atualiza a primeira vez

Tags: javascript, jquery

Esta dando so o primeiro refresh automatico depois para. Segue o que estou usando

```
    var refresh = setInterval( function() 
{
    $('#uohide').load('rand.php');
}, 5000);
```

html     `<div id="uohide></div>`

rand.php `<? echo rand(1, 9999); ?>`

Comment: Porque é que achas que ele só corre uma vez? já experimentaste a colocar `console.log('chamou!);` dentro do setInterval para testar?

Comment: Acho que nesse caso [seria melhor usar o setTimeout](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/77765/129) como callback desse load.

Comment: Outra coisa pra ver também é se a página está sempre recebendo uma mensagem *cached* do rand.php; `$('uohide').load('rand.php?_=' + new Date().getTime());`

Comment: Rapaz era isso mesmo, isso ja resolveu, mas como posso estar retirando o cache dos .php é so no htacces?