# Integrando HTML + Node.js com Angular.js em "Real Time"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-services

Estou com alguns problemas para atualizar automaticamente um código em Angular.js dentro do meu site.
A integração é Node.js com o HTML, integrando com o Angular.js. Porém eu tenho que sempre dar F5 na página para que ele atualize o a variável "Temperatura". Eu gostaria integrar no sistema a atualização automática, ao receber o comando POST no node.js

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**
**index.html**

```
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app="angular">
<div ng-controller="myController">{{data}}</div>

<script>
        var app = angular.module('angular',[]);
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
$scope.data = [];

getData();

function getData () {

    var request = $http.get('/Temperatura');

    request.then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data + " ºC";
    },function(data){
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });

    request.finally(function () {
        $timeout(5000, getData);
    });
    // O finally é executado sempre que a requisição terminar de executar, independente se o retorno for sucesso ou erro

});
</script>
```

**Node.js**

```
app.post('/EnviaTemperatura', function(req, res){
    temperatura = req.body.temp;
    res.send('Temperatura: ' + temperatura);
});

app.get('/Temperatura', function(req, res){
    res.send(temperatura);
});
```

Eu pesquisei para integrar o INTERVAL, um módulo do Angular nesse código, porém não consegui.

Como posso fazer o meu projeto virar "Real Time"?

Comment: Você pode utilizar o $timeout do Angular pra fazer uma requisição a cada x segundos/minutos. Ou então pode utilizar WebSockets

Comment: O timeout não é só pra esperar um tempo e depois executar? @DiegoAugusto

Comment: @jbueno Verdade, me confundi rs. kkk Os dois são um pouco parecidos

Comment: Luiz, boa tarde. Recomendo a leitura de: ["Resolvido" em título de pergunta não fica parecendo coisa de fórum?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5389/resolvido-em-t%C3%ADtulo-de-pergunta-n%C3%A3o-fica-parecendo-coisa-de-f%C3%B3rum)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use o [**`$interval`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) para repetir a consulta num intervalo de tempo.

Uma coisa importante: **não use as funções `success` e `error`**, elas estão obsoletas. No lugar delas deve-se usar a função `then`. [Veja na documentação do AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Vou deixar um exemplo usando `then` no final da resposta.

Só para você ter ciência, é possível fazer com a conexão seja *real time* de verdade, usando [WebSockets](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), mas este não é o assunto da pergunta.

Exemplo:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('angularjsNodejsTutorial',[]);
    app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
        $scope.data = [];

        $interval(function(){
            var request = $http.get('/data');    
            request.success(function(data) {
                $scope.data = data + " ºC";
            })
            .error(function(data){
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
        }, 5000); 

        /* O segundo parâmetro "5000", diz que a função deve ser repetida a cada 
           5000 milisegundos (5 segundos) */

    });
</script>
```

---

Código sem o uso de `success` e `error`. Aqui o primeiro callback é referente ao `success` e o segundo referente ao `error`.

```
$interval(function(){
    var request = $http.get('/data');    

     request.then(function(data) {
                $scope.data = data + " ºC";
            },function(data){
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
        }, 5000);
```

#### Atualização

É importante te dizer que, usando o $interval, se uma das requisições demorar mais que o tempo de repetição (5 segundos, no exemplo), a função será executada novamente, o que pode te trazer problemas. Então, recomendo chamar a função dentro dela mesma combinando com o uso de `$timeout` para atrasar a execução da mesma. Veja mais em [Por que dizem que recursividade de setTimeout é melhor que setInterval?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77764/18246)

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http, $interval) {
    $scope.data = [];

    getData();

    function getData () {

        var request = $http.get('/data');

        request.then(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data + " ºC";
        },function(data){
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });

        request.finally(function () {
            $timeout(5000, getData);
        });
        // O finally é executado sempre que a requisição terminar de executar, independente se o retorno for sucesso ou erro

});
```

Comment: Só complementando, se algo for modificado dentro do $scope da função é preciso utilizar `$scope.apply()`

Comment: deu certo! Obrigado! Por WebSocket é melhor? Eu estou tentando encontrar uma solução melhor para mim. Estava testando em Socket i.o, agora estou pulando para Angular.js e gostaria de ter um processo de Real Time melhor. Qual indica?

Comment: Tem vantagens e desvantagens @LuizHenrique. Você vai ter que entender bem o que precisa e como funciona o WebSocket para decidir o que é melhor. Uma coisa importante (isso não vale apenas para esta pergunta), você sempre pode marcar uma das respostas como correta para as suas perguntas clicando no **✓** abaixo das setas para votar.

Comment: Dependendo do seu escopo, é melhor usar o $digest() ao invés do $apply(). Só uma dica complementar =D

Comment: @jbueno eu sei que não é a pergunta do tópico, mas se eu quiser alterar esse código para só executar quando o método GET mudar? Tipo, eu mandei 100 para GET /data, tem como ele atualizar de novo só quando eu mudar esse valor? Quando eu mandar 80, por exemplo.

Comment: Você diz quando o retorno do servidor for um valor diferente do anterior certo?

Comment: @jbueno isso mesmo.

Comment: @jbueno a ideia é fazer o client receber o dado somente quando tiver um novo comando POST.

Comment: Ok, entendido. E qual o motivo pra atualizar só quando o valor for diferente? É por que você não quer fazer requisições sem motivos (pra não causar nenhum overhead) ou por que a apresentação na view pisca todas as vezes que o valor for modificado? Pergunto isso porque pra cada caso é uma resposta diferente.

Comment: @jbueno na verdade é os 2 motivos, pois como em outro processo ele vai simular algo em Real Time, estou tentando encontrar se a melhor solução é via Angular ou via Socket

Comment: @jbueno eu alterei novamente o código conforme o ultimo que vc enviou, porém apresentou a mensagem abaixo pra mim: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angular' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.