# Delay Javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu preciso rodar um laço `for` a cada 2 segundos, como eu posso fazer ?

```js
for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{        
   console.log(i);                    
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Por que dizem que recursividade de setTimeout é melhor que setInterval?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77764/por-que-dizem-que-recursividade-de-settimeout-%c3%a9-melhor-que-setinterval)

Comment: Acho que não dá pra considerar duplicata, @LucasCosta

Answer (score 1):

Usando a função `setInterval` você pode fazer dessa forma também:

```
let i = 0

const timer = setInterval(function() {
  if (i >= 5) {
    // aborta a execução caso a condição seja atingida
    clearInterval(timer)
  }

  i++
  console.log(i)
}, 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `setInterval`:

```js
function repeticao() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    (function loop(i) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
      }, 2000*i)
    })(i);
  }
}

repeticao();
```

Comment: Então, eu preciso do delay apenas no FOR pois a função será chamada por meio de um botão. Tem outro jeito amigo ?

Comment: Delay entre cada *loop* do `for`?

Comment: Exatamente, eu preciso chamar uma unica vez a função e o laço FOR ficar dando loop a cada x tempo até terminar o laço FOR.

Comment: Editei a resposta @Robotrol

Answer (score -3):

#### How to Make Delay in Javascript

##### Note: `I use Prommise and SetTimeOut`

---

###### 1: Create a async function call => delay

###### 2: create a method or function async

```
//function make delay
async function delay(timeDelay){
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeDelay));
}

//function execute for and use delay!
const exampleWithFor = async ()=>{
    console.log('running example for');
    for (let id = 0; id < 5; id++) {

        console.log('vez: ',id+1)
        var tmp = new Date();
        console.log('timer: ',tmp.toLocaleString());
        console.log("================= \n");
        await delay(2000);
    }
}
//excute this function to use delay
exampleWithFor()
```

---

##### The up Example Resolve Your Problems

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).