# Ajax + Php Passar Variável

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Como posso enviar uma variável através do Ajax e recuperar o valor no PHP?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({
async: true,
url: 'contalog.php',
dataType: 'html',
type: 'POST',
cache: false,
success: function(result){ 
// mandar a variavel $logado que vem do arquivo requisitado aqui acima ....
} 
}); 
}, 1000); 
</script>
```

E usar ela assim no meu PHP, ...

```
echo $logado;
```

Preciso que o `Ajax` execute de tempos em tempos, envie para a variável `$logado` que esta no `PHP`.

Eu sei se eu usar um `include` funciona mas preciso de tempo em tempo via `Ajax` para ter sempre a variável atualizada.

Comment: Seja mais específico em sua pergunta. Você está passando que variável para onde? Poderia colocar o código do "contalog.php" no corpo da pergunta?

Comment: Paulo, considere clicar no botão "editar" e adicionar essas informações na pergunta. Ficando mais claro, podemos te ajudar melhor. Tenho quase certeza que você vai precisar de um "long polling"

Comment: @Wallace Maxters   Feito !

Comment: @Wallace Maxters  Como posso Resolver ?

Comment: Respondi sua pergunta, vê se ajuda :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você precisa verificar de tempo em tempo, considere utilizar [Long Polling](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254506/o-que-%C3%A9-long-polling) para fazê-lo.

Primeiramente, você teria que alterar seu código pra ele usar `setTimeout` com recursão, ao invés de usar `setInterval`, por conta dos problemas descritos [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77764/por-que-dizem-que-recursividade-de-settimeout-%C3%A9-melhor-que-setinterval)

```
(function log() {


    $.ajax({
        url: 'contalog.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(result) { 

            // A variável retornada pelo "contalog.php"
            verificarLogado(result.logado);

            // Só executa no caso de success:
            setTimeout(log, 1000);
        } 
    }); 

})(); 

function verificarLogado(logado) {
    if (logado) {
      alert('Está logado');
    } else {
      alert('Não está logado');
    }
}
```

No seu arquivo `contalog.php`, você deve converter a saída para o formato `JSON` e usar o header correto para reconhecimento do navegador:

```
 #Trecho do código do AP postado no PASTBIN
 // Seleciona da tabela
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logado WHERE hora > :hora GROUP BY ip";
$sql = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sql->bindValue(":hora", date('H:i:s', strtotime("-2 minutes")));
$sql->execute();
$logado = $sql->rowCount();

// Trecho importante

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode(['logado' =>  $logado]);

exit();
```

Comment: @ Wallace Maxters OK vou acrescentar as linhas no contalog.php  e trocar o script js ,  mas não entendi essa parte  

Primeiramente, você teria que alterar seu código pra ele usar setTimeout com recursão, ao invés de usar setInterval

Comment: o Ajax vai me dar a variavel  e eu posso usar ela direto no php  com um echo   ?

Comment: @PauloMaia sabe porque precisa mudar o setInterval pra setTimeout? é o seguinte...  na minha lógica, a função "log" é executada logo de cara. Quando o sucess é chamado, ela executa a mesma função depois de 1000 com setTimeout, quando chegar no success vai executar de novo, porque ela executa ela mesma. O problema de fazer com setInterval é que, se a requisição demorar mais de 1 segundo, vai executar duas vezes, criando uma desordenação na temporização das execuções do ajax.

Comment: @PauloMaia você precisa entender o seguinte: Quando fiz o `echo json_encode(...)`, você está dizendo pro PHP imprimir o valor da variável em formato JSON (o Javascript que executa o AJAX vai entender no `success` que essa variável está no formado Javascript e interpretá-la corretamente). Sem isso, não tem como as duas linguagens se comunicarem, elas tem comportamentos e funcionalidades distintas.

Comment: Sim ,  mas fora do ajax  eu preciso usar a variavel atualizada   $logado,  vou dar um <?php echo $logado; ?>

Comment: @PauloMaia eu acho que você está fazendo uma grande confusão. Onde você quer usar a variável `$logado` "hora do ajax"? Você poderia simplesmente declarar uma função javascript e chamá-la no trecho onde eu coloque um comentário "sua lógica aqui"...

Comment: SIM, o ajax executa o script  e eu preciso do valor retornado para usar no php,  descupe se não estou conseguindo ser claro.

Comment: Editei a resposta. Vê se isso facilita a compreensão da lógica.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68572/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-paulomaia).

Comment: $logado  retorna um numero que pode ser 0  ou ...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, de repente não seria o caso de receber um `push`? Usando [tag:Firebase] do lado do cliente?