# Minutos, Segundos e Milisegundos com setInterval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Fala galera, estou tentando fazer um cronometro simples e quero exibir Minutos, segundos e milissegundos, consigo exibir minutos e segundos, porém alguém me pode me dar uma luz em relação aos milissegundos?

o método abaixo é executado a cada segundo, mas se eu colocar ao invés de 1000 colocar 1 a função vai ser executada a cada milissegundo, como eu faço o cálculo de conversão?

```
this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.minutos = Math.floor(++this.segundosTotais / 60 );
      this.segundos = this.segundosTotais - this.minutos * 60;
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Converter o que?

Comment: Seria mais interessante você dar mais detalhes do que gostaria de fazer. Acho que está um pouco confuso.

Comment: Quero fazer um cronômetro que exiba minutos, segundos e milissegundos, bem, parecido com o cronômetro nativo do Android onde o usuário entra com os minutos que desejar daí em diante vou fazer algumas manipulações de cor, gravar dados etc...

Answer (score 1):

> se eu colocar ao invés de 1000 colocar 1 a função vai ser executada a cada milissegundo

Em teoria sim, mas na prática, não. O engine do JavaScript não dá conta de executar 1000 vezes por segundo as funções passadas ao `setInterval`. Na melhor hipótese, você vai conseguir algo como uma execução a cada 40ms. Além disso, o `setInterval` vai descartar execuções encavaladas que não consiga atender. Para mais detalhes sobre isso, ver [Por que dizem que recursividade de setTimeout é melhor que setInterval?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77764).

> como eu faço o cálculo de conversão

Não dá para saber com esse código, porque não sabemos o tipo do seu objeto `this`. Se fosse uma data (por exemplo, o retorno de `new Date()`), seria possível chamar o método [`getMilliseconds()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds), que retorna os milissegundos do valor da data. Se esse seu objeto não tem o valor com precisão de milissegundos, apenas segundos, não será possível exibir os milissegundos da data.