# Excesso de uso de memoria com timer no javascript

Tags: javascript, memória

Estou querendo colocar um timer numa pagina, a função funciona, mostra o tempo progressivamente, mas percebi que o uso do "setInterval()" começa a consumir muito processamento da pagina até o ponto do navegador travar por segurança.

Por que depois quero calcular a diferença da hora atual e a hora que abriu a pagina. Tem outro jeito de fazer?

```
function tempo(){

 var hora = document.getElementById('hora');

 var data = new Date(); 
 hora.value = data.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR');


 verificarHorario();
 setInterval(tempo ,1000);
}

function verificarDiferencaHorario(inicialMin, finalMin) {
 var totalMin = Number(finalMin - inicialMin);
 var hora2 = document.getElementById('hora2');

 hora2.value = ((Math.trunc(totalMin / 60).toString() + ":" + (totalMin % 60).toString()));
}

function verificarHorario() {

 var inicial = "11:20"; //teste

 var hora = document.getElementById('hora');
 var final = "12:20"; //teste
 var splInicial = inicial.split(":"), splFinal = final.split(":");

 var inicialMin = (Number(splInicial[0] * 60)) + Number(splInicial[1]);
 var finalMin = (Number(splFinal[0] * 60)) + Number(splFinal[1]);

 verificarDiferencaHorario(inicialMin, finalMin);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem como melhorar esse código...

1. Crie as referências para os elementos fora das funções, assim só serão criadas uma vez
2. Use funções recursivas com `setTimeout` em vez de usar `setInterval`, pode melhorar ([motivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77764)), mas não necessariamente vai
3. Não crie uma nova instância da Date, apenas "atualize" a antiga

Código:

```js
const hora = document.getElementById('hora');

const hora2 = document.getElementById('hora2');

const data = new Date();

(function tempo() {
  hora.value = data.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR');

  verificarHorario();

  data.setSeconds(data.getSeconds() + 1)

  setTimeout(tempo, 1000);
})();

function verificarDiferencaHorario(inicialMin, finalMin) {
  var totalMin = Number(finalMin - inicialMin);
  hora2.value = ((Math.trunc(totalMin / 60).toString() + ":" + (totalMin % 60).toString()));
}

function verificarHorario() {
  var inicial = "11:20"; //teste
  var final = "12:20"; //teste

  var splInicial = inicial.split(":"),
      splFinal = final.split(":");

  var inicialMin = (Number(splInicial[0] * 60)) + Number(splInicial[1]);
  var finalMin = (Number(splFinal[0] * 60)) + Number(splFinal[1]);

  verificarDiferencaHorario(inicialMin, finalMin);
}
```

```html
<input id="hora" readonly>
<input id="hora2" readonly>
```

Comment: Não funcionou, os input não recebem os e a variavel data não atualiza. O que resolveu meu problema foi remover o setInterval da função tempo e colocar fora do escopo da função. assim: var myVar = setInterval(tempo, 1000);