# Como posso criar uma função de pausa e resumo da função setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Preciso criar uma espécie de pausa e *resume*, pode ser com JavaScript (sem jQuery).

Tenho um *slide* de fotos, cada foto aparece de 3 em 3 segundos com `setTimeout()` e dessa forma (como vêem as funções estão encadeadas para não acontecer atrasos):

```
setTimeout(function() {
  //mostrar uma imagem

  setTimeout(function() {
    //mostra outra

    setTimeout(function() {
      //assim sucessivamente...
    }, 3000);
  }, 3000);
}, 0);
```

Então procurei em alguns fóruns de ajuda e encontrei somente uma função que pára o *script*, mas não foi útil pois preciso de algo que dê pausa no `setTimeout` e logo depois posso dar um *resume* novamente, até tentei uma função de `Timer()` com orientação a objetos, porém ela só funciona uma vez não é possível encadear as funções como fiz com `setTimeout()`.

Veja os teste que fiz e algumas funções que tentei usar mais uma só funcionou uma vez para pausar a de `Timer()`, notem que eu adicionei um *onload* para carregar algumas alertas se eu usar o Timer para pausar elas somente pausa um setTimeout, não pausa todos, e quero que pause todos de vez e quando apertar em retornar ele retorne de onde parou no `setTimeout()`;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Funções de Tempo</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function alertas() {
   // var timer = new Timer(function() {
   //  alert('Tempo Final');
   // }, 10000);

   setTimeout(function() {
    alert('1 vez');

   setTimeout(function() {
    alert('2 vez');

   setTimeout(function() {
    alert('3 vez');
   }, 3000);
   }, 3000);
   }, 3000);
  }
  function Timer(callback, delay) {
      var timerId, start, remaining = delay;

      this.pause = function() {
          window.clearTimeout(timerId);
          remaining -= Date.now() - start;
      };

      this.resume = function() {
          start = Date.now();
          window.clearTimeout(timerId);
          timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
      };

      this.resume();
  }

  // var timer = new Timer(function() {
  //     alert("Done!");
  // }, 1000);

  var timer = new Timer(function() {
   alert('ok');
  }, 3000);

  // timer.pause();
  // Do some stuff...
  // timer.resume();
  function pausar() {
   alert('pausado!');
   timer.pause();
  }
  function continuar() {
   alert('Retornando');
   timer.resume();
  }
  function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
      if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
        break;
      }
    }
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="alertas()">
   <button onclick="pausar()">Pausa</button>
   <button onclick="continuar()">Retornar</button>
   <!-- <button onclick="iniciar()">Iniciar</button> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: não dá pra fazer uma "pausa" no `setTimeout`, o que pode fazer é cancelar com o `clearTimeout` e controlar a sua pausa num loop ou evento, e quanto a pausa acabar, iniciar novamente o `setTimeout`. Detalhe: para fazer isso, associe o `setTimeout` a uma variável

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo, vou tentar fazer isto!

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a parte do resumo, mas, no caso aí não seria melhor utilizar **setInterval()** ao invés de setTimeout()?

Comment: Eu não sei exatamente como funciona o setInterval(), quase que achei que a função dele seria quase a mesma do setTimeout

Comment: Posso dar uma pesquisada sobre ele, mais o que preciso mesmo é de um botão no html que pause e da resumo no setTimeout, o mesmo como se fosse um vídeo você pausa e da play de novo pra continuar

Comment: Não é "resumo", é "retomada".... a palavra "resumo" significa "síntese", algo mais curto, resumido. O termo em inglês "resume" não significa "resumo". É um falso cognato.

Comment: Seria isso https://jsfiddle.net/z7dsk32a/ ? - aproveitando, `setTimeout` executa algo apenas uma vez, enquanto `setInterval` executa indefinidamente, ou até que seja interrompido por um `clearInterval`. Por fim, vale a leitura: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77764/112052

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia criar um classe *timer*.

Exemplo:

```js
function mytimer() {
  this.time = 0;
  this.pause = false;
  this.update = function() {
    if (!this.pause) {this.time += 1};
      slide();
}
  this.intervalo = setInterval(this.update,1000);
}
var myslide = new mytimer();
function slide() {
  if (myslide.time == 3) {
    alert("Slide 1");
}
  if (myslide.time == 6) {
    alert("Slide 2");
}
  if (myslide.time == 9) {
    alert("Slide 3");
    myslide.pause = true;
  }

}

function pause() {
  myslide.pause = true
}
function resume() {
myslide = false;
}
```

Ou

```js
setTimeOut(myfunction,3000);
var time = {
  value: 0,
  pause: false
}
function myfunction() {
  if (!time.pause) {
   time.value += 1;
   if (time.value == 1) {
    alert("Slide 1");
   }
  if (time.value == 2) {
    alert("Slide 2");
  }
  if (time.value == 3) {
    alert("Slide 3");
    time.pause = true;
  }
   setTimeOut(myfunction,3000);
  }
}
function pause() {
  time.pause = true
}
function resume() {
  time.pause = false;
  setTimeOut(myfunction,3000);
}
```

Comment: Olá obrigado pela ajuda, vou fazer uns testes usando essas funções assim que eu puder e retorno depois se deu certo.

Comment: Você pode também pode adiciona outras ferramentas na classe: Resetar a time,nome da time e etcs. Se quiser te passo o código completo.

Comment: Valeu, se puder pode me mandar sim por favor, mais vejo que vou precisar estudar um pouco a estrutura para entender como está funcionando, pq só olhando não da pra saber se realmente vai funcionar sabe, só testando na prática mesmo, se eu conseguir compartilho meu resultado aqui rs

Comment: https://gitlab.com/maurygta2/timer_js/blob/master/timer.js Meu projeto escolar você pode ler,ta confuso,porque esse foi meu  primeiro código.

Comment: Obrigado rs, depois dou uma estudada nele.

Comment: Não use cumprimentos ou saudações, veja [que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)