# Como parar um intervalo com o clearInterval e continuá-lo depois?

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

Estou fazendo um código para fazer um jogo de digitação: ao digitar a palavra corretamente o usuário ganha um tempo a mais no tempo que está sendo decrescido e ganha 1 ponto, e perde se chegar no 0s.

Por exemplo: se acerta a palavra quando está em 7s, esse tempo vai para 9 segundos.

Porém quando o evento de acertar a palavra é disparado, eu limpo o intervalo e seto a variável correspondente ao intervalo para chamar a função de novo, agora com os segundos a adicionar ao tempo (no caso 2s), mas o jogo começa a se comportar de forma estranha e não faz o que a função deveria continuar fazendo, então acho que essa função não está sendo chamada.

A função para `setInterval` só pode ser chamada uma vez por ele? Ou então ao limpar o intervalo não tem como continuá-lo?

```js
var word = document.getElementById("word");
var wordTyped = document.getElementById("text");
var time = document.getElementById("time");
var score = document.getElementById("score");
var endGame = document.querySelector(".end-game-container");
const settingsBtn = document.getElementById("settings-btn");
const difficultySettings = document.getElementById("settings");
var secondsInterval = setInterval(updateTime, 1000, 0);
var currentTime = Number(
  time.textContent.substring(0, time.textContent.length - 1)
);
const words = [
  "bad",
  "view",
  "world",
  "release",
  "caracteristic",
  "grass",
  "homeland",
  "building",
  "juice",
  "illness",
];

//FUNÇÃO QUE GERA UMA PALAVRA NOVA NA TELA AO ACERTAR A ANTERIOR
function randomWord(secondsToAdd) {
  if (secondsToAdd > 0) {
    clearInterval(secondsInterval);
    secondsInterval = setInterval(updateTime, 1000, secondsToAdd);//PARTE QUE O CÓDIGO PARA DE FUNCIONAR DE FORMA NORMAL JÁ QUE OS SEGUNDOS A ADICIONAR É MAIOR QUE 0 POIS É CHAMADA QUANDO ACERTOU A PALAVRA
  }
  let selectedWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  word.textContent = selectedWord;
}

function lostTheGame() {
  endGame.style.display = "flex";
  endGame.innerHTML = `<h1>Time ran out</h1> <p> Your final score is ${score.innerHTML} <button onclick=reload() > Reload </button>`;
}

function reload() {
  wordTyped.value = "";
  time.textContent = "10s";
  score.textContent = "0";
  randomWord(0);
  updateTime(0);
  endGame.style.display = "none";
}
//FUNÇÃO CORRESPONDENTE AO INTERVALO
function updateTime(secondsToAdd) {
  time.textContent = `${currentTime}s`;
  if (currentTime == 0) {
    clearInterval(secondsInterval);
    lostTheGame();
  }
  currentTime += secondsToAdd;
  currentTime--;
}

wordTyped.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  if (wordTyped.value == word.textContent) {
    randomWord(2);
    wordTyped.value = "";
    score.innerHTML = +score.innerHTML + 1;
  }
});
randomWord(0);

settingsBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  difficultySettings.classList.toggle("hide");
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

select {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #a7c5e3;
}

select:focus,
button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.settings-btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 30px;
}

.settings {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.settings.hide {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.container {
  background-color: #34495e;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
}

h2 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.score-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  right: 20px;
}

.time-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 20px;
}

.end-game-container {
  background-color: inherit;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha256-+N4/V/SbAFiW1MPBCXnfnP9QSN3+Keu+NlB+0ev/YKQ="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Speed Typer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="settings-btn" class="settings-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
    </button>

    <div id="settings" class="settings">
      <form id="settings-form">
        <div>
          <label for="difficulty">Difficulty</label>
          <select id="difficulty">
            <option value="easy">Easy</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="hard">Hard</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <h2>‍ Speed Typer ‍</h2>
      <small>Type the following:</small>

      <h1 id="word"></h1>

      <input
        type="text"
        id="text"
        autocomplete="off"
        placeholder="Type the word here..."
      />

      <p class="time-container">Time left: <span id="time">10s</span></p>

      <p class="score-container">Score: <span id="score">0</span></p>

      <div id="end-game-container" class="end-game-container"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema, a meu ver, é que você está misturando diferentes responsabilidades nas mesmas funções. Por exemplo, a função que escolhe a palavra aleatória também é responsável por atualizar a contagem, tem mais de um lugar que soma os segundos ao tempo atual, etc.

Em vez de tentar corrigir o seu código, eu decidir reescrever uma parte dele, para separar melhor as responsabilidades de cada função. No exemplo abaixo retirei o CSS e parte do HTML para focar somente no algoritmo em si (mas depois você adiciona o que precisar):

```js
var word = document.getElementById("word");
var wordTyped = document.getElementById("text");
var timeLeft = document.getElementById("time-left");
var score = document.getElementById("score");
var endGame = document.querySelector(".end-game-container");
const words = [ "bad", "view", "world", "release", "caracteristic", "grass", "homeland", "building", "juice", "illness" ];
var currentWordIndex = -1;
var secondsInterval = null;

// número aleatório entre min e max
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// escolhe a palavra aleatória e atualiza o input - e só
function chooseWord() {
  // soma um valor entre 1 e (tamanho do array - 1), assim a próxima palavra não será repetida
  currentWordIndex = (currentWordIndex + randomInteger(1, words.length - 1)) % words.length;
  word.textContent = words[currentWordIndex];
  wordTyped.value = "";
}

// atualiza a contagem regressiva (diminui 1 do tempo e vê se chegou a zero)
function countdown() {
  var currentTime = parseInt(timeLeft.textContent) - 1;
  timeLeft.textContent = currentTime;
  if (currentTime == 0) {
    clearInterval(secondsInterval); // se terminou o jogo, para a contagem regressiva
    lostTheGame();
  }
}

function lostTheGame() {
  endGame.style.display = "flex";
  endGame.innerHTML = `<h1>Time ran out</h1> <p> Your final score is ${score.innerHTML} <button onclick=reload() > Reload </button>`;
}

function reload() { // reseta as configurações do jogo
  wordTyped.value = "";
  timeLeft.textContent = "10";
  score.textContent = "0";
  chooseWord();
  endGame.style.display = "none";
  // crio o interval aqui - e somente aqui
  secondsInterval = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}

function addTime(seconds) { // adiciona segundos ao tempo atual
  timeLeft.textContent = parseInt(timeLeft.textContent) + seconds;
}

wordTyped.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  // se acertou, adiciona 2 segundos e escolhe nova palavra
  if (wordTyped.value == word.textContent) {
    addTime(2);
    chooseWord();
    score.innerHTML = parseInt(score.innerHTML) + 1;
  }
});

// o jogo começa com as configurações iniciais (que no fundo é o mesmo que um reload)
reload();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <small>Type the following:</small>
  <h1 id="word"></h1>
  <input type="text" id="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type the word here...">
  <p class="time-container">Time left: <span id="time-left">10</span>s</p>
  <p class="score-container">Score: <span id="score">0</span></p>
  <div id="end-game-container" class="end-game-container"></div>
</div>
```

Também mudei a forma de escolher a palavra aleatória, para evitar que haja repetição (da forma que você fez, havia a chance de ser a mesma).

E no `span` que contém o tempo restante, deixei apenas o valor numérico (o "s" ficou de fora), assim fica mais fácil pegar somente o número no código.

---

#### Outra opção

Em vez de `setInterval`, você poderia usar `setTimeout`. Assim você não precisa se preocupar em limpar o *timer*, e você só chama-o novamente caso não esteja zerado:

```js
var word = document.getElementById("word");
var wordTyped = document.getElementById("text");
var timeLeft = document.getElementById("time-left");
var score = document.getElementById("score");
var endGame = document.querySelector(".end-game-container");
const words = [ "bad", "view", "world", "release", "caracteristic", "grass", "homeland", "building", "juice", "illness" ];
var currentWordIndex = -1;

function randomInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function chooseWord() {
  currentWordIndex = (currentWordIndex + randomInteger(1, words.length - 1)) % words.length;
  word.textContent = words[currentWordIndex];
  wordTyped.value = "";
}

function countdown() {
  var currentTime = parseInt(timeLeft.textContent) - 1;
  timeLeft.textContent = currentTime;
  // se zerou, acaba o jogo; senão, continua a contagem regressiva
  if (currentTime == 0) {
    lostTheGame();
  } else setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}

function lostTheGame() {
  endGame.style.display = "flex";
  endGame.innerHTML = `<h1>Time ran out</h1> <p> Your final score is ${score.innerHTML} <button onclick=reload() > Reload </button>`;
}

function reload() {
  wordTyped.value = "";
  timeLeft.textContent = "10";
  score.textContent = "0";
  chooseWord();
  endGame.style.display = "none";
  setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}

function addTime(seconds) {
  timeLeft.textContent = parseInt(timeLeft.textContent) + seconds;
}

wordTyped.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  if (wordTyped.value == word.textContent) {
    addTime(2);
    chooseWord();
    score.innerHTML = parseInt(score.innerHTML) + 1;
  }
});

reload();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <small>Type the following:</small>

  <h1 id="word"></h1>

  <input type="text" id="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type the word here...">

  <p class="time-container">Time left: <span id="time-left">10</span>s</p>

  <p class="score-container">Score: <span id="score">0</span></p>
  <div id="end-game-container" class="end-game-container"></div>
</div>
```

Para saber mais sobre a diferença entre [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) e [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77764/112052).