# Recuperar retorno de callback

Tags: javascript, google-maps, callback

Tenho a função abaixo que calcula distancias usando uma API do Google.

Gostaria de saber como ter o retorno da função de *callback*.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_global/_js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=my_key"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CalculaDistancia(origem, destino) {
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix(  {
            origins: [origem],
            destinations: [destino],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, callback);
        return callback;
    }
    function callback(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            distancia = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
            km = distancia/1000;
            kmr = Math.ceil(km/100);
            frete = kmr * 100;
            alert (frete);
        }
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:CalculaDistancia('36880000', '28890185');">calcular</a>
```

Da forma como está, o `alert(frete)` alerta normalmente.

Mas não consigo recuperar esse valor de dentro da função `CalculaDistancia()`.

Comment: Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required

Comment: exatamente assim

Comment: Carlos, já chegou a testar alguma das soluções? falta adicionar alguma coisa em alguma delas?

Answer (score 1):

Quando tens `service.getDistanceMatrix({...}, callback);` o que acontece é que esse método recebe dois argumentos. Um objeto, e uma função. E com isso a função/método é consumida e o retorno será passado à callback.

Qualquer conteúdo que `service.getDistanceMatrix` retornar será passado à callback e já não podes usar dentro de `CalculaDistancia`, pelo menos da maneira como está.

Se tens mais código que precise de `response, status` então ou inseres esse código dentro da callback, ou mudas a callback passada a  `service.getDistanceMatrix`. Um exemplo da segunda opção seria assim:

```
function CalculaDistancia(origem, destino) {
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(  {
        origins: [origem],
        destinations: [destino],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function(response, status){
       // aqui podes fazer algo com "response" e "status"
       // pois esta função é uma callback do método
       alert(response);
       // e depois:
       callback(response, status);
    });
```

Comment: No caso do `if (status == ...) {` é mais apropriado resolver no *callback* de `service.getDistanceMatrix` ou na função `callback`? *+1*

Comment: @stderr depende da estrutura e lógica do código. É dificil responder de maneira geral. `+1` também para a tua resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Além da alternativa [sugerida pelo Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/159195/6454), uma vez que  [**Distance Matrix**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix?hl=pt-br) é um serviço assíncrono, você pode usar uma [**Promessa**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) para o processamento assíncrono.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
function CalculaDistancia(origem, destino) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

    service.getDistanceMatrix({
      origins: [origem],
      destinations: [destino],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, 
    function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
          resolve(response);
      } else {
          reject(status);
      }
    }); 
  });
}
                                          
CalculaDistancia('36880000', '28890185')
  .then(function(response) {
     distancia = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;

     km = distancia/1000;
     kmr = Math.ceil(km/100);

     frete = kmr * 100;
     console.log('O valor do frete é: ' + frete);

   }, function(status) {
     console.log('Não foi possível realizar a operação! Status: ' + status);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=3&sensor=false&key=TUA_KEY_AQUI"></script>
```

<sub>**Nota**: No lugar de `TUA_KEY_AQUI` coloque a tua chave, se você não tiver, veja como obter nessa página: [**Get a Key/Authentication**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=pt-br).</sub>

Veja também:

- [O que são *promises* (promessas) em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119907/6454)
- [Como programação assíncrona funciona em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16950/6454)