# Como verificar se arquivo existe no Storage do Firebase web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-storage

Estou fazendo uma aplicação web com o firebase, nessa aplicação tenho um cadastro de imagens (opcional), semelhante a ideia de um perfil (o usuário pode ter ou não uma imagem cadastrada se não tiver é carregado uma imagem padrão), gostaria de saber como faço para verificar se existe um arquivo daquele usuário?

Obs: para "relacionar" o banco de dados (realtime database) com o armazenamento (storage) eu cadastro as imagens usando a chave do usuário como nome, por exemplo cadastro de usuário com uma chave xyz, se ele cadastrar uma imagem, ela vai estar em `firebase.storage().ref('xyz')`

Se o modo como eu uso estiver errado me digam a forma certa de se fazer.

Pensei primeiro em criar uma `chave: valor` com o caminho para a imagem no banco de dados, mas achei ocupação de espaço desnecessário, além disso teria que, de algum modo, verificar o nome do arquivo para não repetir

Para mostrar os dados eu chamo a função `mostrar()` dentro do `forEach` de leitura:

```
function ler() {
database.ref(referencia_database).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var chave = childSnapshot.key
            var obj = childSnapshot.val()
            var urlImagem;

            storage.ref(chave).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                // A imagem existe
                urlImagem = url;
                console.log(urlImagem);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                switch (error.code) {
                    case 'storage/object_not_found':
                        // A imagem não existe
                        urlImagem = './image/default.png';
                        console.log(urlImagem);
                        break;

                    default:
                        // Ocorreu um erro desconhecido
                        break;
                }
            });

            mostrar(chave, obj.nome, urlImagem)
        })
    })
}

function mostrar(chave, nome, url) {
    div.innerHTML +=    '<a href="#container">' + 
                                '<div class="col s12 m4 l3" onclick="selecionar(\'' + chave + '\')">' +
                                    '<div class="card">' + 
                                        '<div class="card-image">' +
                                            '<img src="' + url + '">' +
                                            '<span class="card-title">' + nome + '</span>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>' + 
                            '</a>'
}
```

Comment: Tem como mostrar o `forEach` também? Porque do jeito que está não consigo ver que valores estão sendo passados para a função `mostrar()`.

Comment: Coloquei as duas funções, a que lê os dados e a que mostra

Comment: Muito bem. O que acontece é que a função `getDownloadURL()` é [assíncrona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950/como-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-funciona-em-javascript). Isso significa que no momento em que você chama a `mostrar()`, o valor da `urlImagem` ainda não foi definido. Por isso que você deve chamar a `mostrar` no `then()` ou no `catch()` como mostro na minha resposta editada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar obter a URL de download da imagem. Se ocorrer o [erro `object_not_found`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors?hl=pt-br) é porque ela não existe.

```
var ref = firebase.storage().ref('xyz');
var urlImagem;
ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // A imagem existe
  urlImagem = url;
  console.log(urlImagem);
  mostrar(chave, obj.nome, urlImagem)
}).catch(function(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'storage/object_not_found':
      // A imagem não existe
      urlImagem = './image/default.png';
      console.log(urlImagem);
      mostrar(chave, obj.nome, urlImagem)
      break;

    default:
      // Ocorreu um erro desconhecido
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Não deu certo na pergunta está como fiz no código

Comment: Você não precisa formar a URL manualmente, a função `getDownloadURL()` retorna a URL da imagem (editei a minha resposta para mostrar isso). Experimente a resposta actualizada. Você testou os 2 casos? Quando a imagem existe e quando não existe? Nenhum dos 2 mostrou algo na consola?

Comment: Sim testei os dois, um da o erro 404 no console e o outro aparece a url do firebase. E na tag aparece `<img src(unknown)>`. Testei desse outro modo que tu fez mas também não funcionou

Comment: Eu esqueci de trocar os nomes das variáveis, o console mostra a mesma coisa mas a tag fica agora `<img src="undefined">`

Comment: Você pode mostrar o código que está usando para colocar a url na tag img?

Comment: adicionei na pergunta

Comment: Entendi, pensei que seria algo assim, a url ter sido enviada vazia antes de ser verificada e setada o valor correto. Funcionou com a imagem mas quando não existe uma imagem a default.png não é enviada (aparece apenas uma div em a função mostrar não é chama eu acho)

Comment: Tirei o `switch case`, assim a imagem padrao será carregada em qualquer caso de erro e funcionou acho que estava entrando em outro codigo de erro. Mas mais uma dúvida se tu puder me ajudar, o `getDownloadURL()` faz o carregamento da imagem? Se sim isso não causa uma queda de performance, ja que a mesma imagem seria carregada duas vezes?

Comment: Sim, o `getDownloadURL()` faz o carregamento da imagem. Mas como assim 2 vezes? Você está chamando `getDownloadURL()` mais de uma vez?

Comment: Não, mas quando eu fasso o `innerHTML` da imagem (`<img>`), o html não vai carregar essa imagem denvo?

Comment: Quando eu falei "carregamento" me referia ao processo de ler a imagem do Firebase. (Acho que você está falando do carregamento de mostrar a imagem na página). Então não, o `getDownloadURL` não vai carregar a imagem para a página, isso é o `innerHTML` que faz e faz uma vez só.