# Retornar valor de uma função NODE

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá

Estou iniciando com NODE. Tenho a função abaixo e gostaria que ela retornasse o texto traduzido. Hoje ela joga o texto para o console. Como faço para ela retornar o texto? Como ficaria? Obrigado.

```
function traduzirTexto() {
  // ==> Aqui vamos configurar os requests
  let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    baseUrl: endpoint,
    url: 'translate',
    qs: {
      'api-version': '3.0',
      'to': ['en', 'es']
    },
    headers: {
      'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'X-ClientTraceId': uuidv4().toString()
    },
    body: [{
      'text': 'Olá Desenvolvedor!'
    }],
    json: true,
  }

  // ==> Aqui vamos imprimir a nossa requisição
  request(options, (err, res, body) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(body, null, 4));
  })
};
```

---

Galera eu perguntei o que mudaria no código para funcionar, era só isso que queria saber se alguém soubesse, pra agilizar um projeto aqui. Não perguntei sobre onde conseguir tutoriais de callback.

Comment: Faça a função `traduzirTexto` receber um **[callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-é-callback)**. Isso é necessário dada a natureza assíncrona do JavaScript.

Comment: Ainda não está claro pra mim.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [O que é callback?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177), [Como programação assíncrona funciona em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950), [O que são promises (promessas) em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119907), e tem mais

Answer (score -2):

Deixar aqui a função que precisava, caso alguém precise:

```
async t(texto) {

    if (this.idioma !== 'pt') {

        const res = await axios({
            baseURL: process.env.TRANSLATOR_TEXT_ENDPOINT,
            url: '/translate',
            method: 'post',
            responseType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': process.env.TRANSLATOR_TEXT_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY,
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region': process.env.TRANSLATOR_TEXT_REGION,
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'X-ClientTraceId': process.env.TRANSLATOR_TEXT_ID
            },
            params: {
                'api-version': '3.0',
                'from': 'pt',
                'to': [this.idioma]
            },
            data: [{
                'text': texto
            }]
        });
        texto = res.data[0]['translations'][0].text;            
    }

    return texto;
}
```