# Executar função em javascript em paralelo

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises

Galera já vi algumas perguntas porém não entendi bem ao certo, depois de algumas pesquisas vi que era possível fazer isto usando promises! Então peguei uma função no Google e modifiquei algumas coisas, porém não tenho certeza que está executando em paralelo, vocês podem me dizer se estou correto? Minha função é a seguinte:

```js
function someCall() {
  console.log('texto 1')
}

function anotherCall() {
  console.log('2');
}
console.time('teste1')
Promise.allSettled([someCall(), anotherCall()]);
console.timeEnd('teste1')
```

**Quero saber se as funções estão sendo executadas ao mesmo tempo**

Minha pergunta talvez seja simples mais estou muito confuso em relação a isso, como vou saber se está sendo executadas ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Não, o que preciso é que várias funções da minha aplicação execute ao mesmo tempo, não todas mais algumas, algumas funções são coisais simples, mais que quero executar em paralelo. Dei essa função que fiz de exemplo porque se eu estiver correto irei conseguir fazer o resto sozinho, pode me tirar a dúvida, se essa função está executando em paralelo?

Comment: Em JavaScript nada executa ao mesmo tempo. Execução assíncrona é outra coisa. Para executar algo realmente em paralelo, só usando workers, mas isso é pra casos específicos. Será que você não está tentando fazer uma otimização prematura?

Comment: Para explicação sobre o funcionamento das funções assíncronas, ver https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16960

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A documentação diz o seguinte:

> [`allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)
>
> O método [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) retorna uma promessa que é resolvida após todas as promessas dadas serem resolvidas ou rejeitadas, com um `array` de objetos que descrevem o resultado de cada promessa.

Ou seja, no seu caso não funcionará da forma que você espera porque as suas funções não são assíncronas.

Para conseguir o resultado desejado você deveria usar funções que retornam promessas:

```js
const executar = async (texto, ms) => {
  await aguardar(ms);
  console.log(texto);
};

const aguardar = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async () => {
  console.time('Execução');
  await Promise.allSettled([executar('primeiro', 50), executar('segundo', 10)]);
  console.timeEnd('Execução');
})();
```

Note que no exemplo acima coloquei uma função `aguardar` que tem por objetivo mudar o tempo de execução da função, evidenciando a diferença das execuções.

---

> [**Funções assíncronas**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas)
>
> A declaração **async function** define uma função assíncrona, que retorna um objeto [`AsyncFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction).
>
> Você também pode definir funções assíncronas usando uma [expressão `async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function).
>
> Quando uma função assíncrona é chamada, ela retorna uma [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Quando a função assíncrona retorna um valor, a `Promise` será resolvida com o valor retornado. Quando a função assíncrona lança uma exceção ou algum valor, a `Promise` será rejeitada com o valor lançado.
>
> Uma função assíncrona pode conter uma expressão [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), que pausa a execução da função assíncrona e espera pela resolução da `Promise` passada, e depois retoma a execução da função assíncrona e retorna o valor resolvido.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem pra que serve a função aguardar pode me explicar melhor?

Comment: Se mudar o tempo da primeira e segundo que está 50 pra primeiro, e 10 para o segundo pra 0 nos dois ainda sim vai executar simultaneamente?

Comment: @user210827 sim. A função aguardar serve apenas para que fique evidente que as duas funções executam ao mesmo tempo

Comment: Okay, mas tem como eu fazer sem o setTimeout? Como ficaria ? Desculpa sou um pouco leigo com programação assíncrona.